# Capture high speed webcam and process frames using threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing, webcam, task-parallel-library

I have a PS3 Eye webcam capable of delivering frames up to 120 times a second based on the resolution.

I need to do some processing on each frame, and currently that takes up quite a lot of time.
The webcam is set to 60 fps, that leaves around 16 ms of processing time per frame, but due to the processing bottleneck, i am only able to retrieve around 30 frames a second.

Behind the scenes a while loop retrieves the bitmap data from the camera, and sets a bitmap property, and notifies that a new frame has been retrieved, so the images wont stack up if processing takes too long.

I am thinking i should be able to somehow use threading to make the processing "faster".

Perhaps like this

1. Frame received
2. Thread 1 starts processing
3. Frame received
4. Thread 1 is busy
5. Thread 2 starts processing
6. Thread 1 finished processing
7. Frame received
8. Thread 1 starts processing
9. Thread 2 finished processing
10. Etc

Do you guys think threading, perhaps by using the Task Parallel library will improve performance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea should work. Theoretically you should now be able to "double time" and get to the desired 60FPS.

One problem:

1. Frame received
2. Thread 1 starts processing
3. Frame received
4. Thread 1 is busy
5. Thread 2 starts processing
6. Frame received

Whoops, now what, both are busy. So you might want to have a 3rd thread to act like a "server" which fetches the images, queues and serves them to you "worker" threads.

Comment: The problem you describe shoudnt really be much of a problem, what would happen is that the frame would just be skipped, and if it is running 40% faster, i should be able to live with that :) The "server" serving the images to the thread will just be my main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Threading should help, and the model is a producer-consumer problem

Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

I do the exact same thing in my research as I read from high speed cameras (~360 fps) and need to process every frame quickly. I have one thread setup to just read from the camera and then stuff into a queue (producer). As images are added, a counting semaphore is incremented. Then I have a couple of consumers (typically three) which then pull images from the queue, process the data, and update the model.

Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)

Comment: Yeah that's what i figured :) Do you perhaps have any other performance enhancing tricks up your sleeve?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. I have a hard realtime requirement since I do structured light scanning and image processing, so I am very good about memory management (I'm in C++). Are you using OpenCV for the processing? If so you might be able to use its GPU computing component (just recently added). Otherwise bust out the profiler and see what part of your processing is taking the longest. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using AForge, but recently i did a few tests and C++ seems SO much faster. I haven't decided to go the c++ route yet, but i may :) Thank you for your input!